# Setting Column and Row Names from Cell in uitable - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I am using GUIDE to build my first GUI interface in MATLAB.

I have several matrices I want to display using the `uitable`. For now let's focus on one matrix, say `myMatrix [10x5]`

Now I have two cells of strings, `columnNames (1x5)`, and another, `rowNames (10x1)`. I would like to set these cells to the row and column names of the table, but I cant yet figure out how to do this.

The MATLAB help page says you can use a cell of strings to do this, however in the property inspector, and under ColumnName, the only non-numeric option is to enter the names manually.

Any help would be appreciated (or suggestions to go about this in a different way).

Comment: Just to clarify, you're having a hard time setting up custom column and row names of the table?

Comment: Yes. Since I will be pulling column names from a data file, and will be having several tables, I don't want to insert the column names manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have custom Row/Column Names you have to pass a cell of strings (using `{<names>}`) into the `ColumnName` and `RowName` properties of the `uitable`.  Here is an example directly from [MatLab's `uitable` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html):

```
f = figure('Position',[200 200 400 150]);
dat = rand(3); 
cnames = {'X-Data','Y-Data','Z-Data'};  % These are your column names
rnames = {'First','Second','Third'};    % These are your row names
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,'Position',[20 20 360 100]);
```

When parsing you're file, be sure to create the lists as a *cell of strings*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, KronoS. It should be possible to do that in the GUIDE generated m-file as well?

Comment: In theory yes, but I've found that GUIDE creation of GUI's is rather a pain. I suggest the use of [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) if you're planning on creating anything remotely complicated.

Comment: That looks great, thanks! And yes MATLAB's GUIDE is terribly confusing. I'll look into GUI Layout Toolbox.

Comment: Just a comment for future users, it was much much simpler to write the GUI code than to use GUIDE.